# What does the $am() function do in jqMobi/jQuery?

Tags: jqmobi

I keep seeing this $am() function calling in jq.ui.js, but I can't find the definition anywhere...what does this function do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's in jq.ui.js at the bottom. It's just a wrapper to document.getElementById() that was used in aUX (jqUi was derived from this, which was before the query selector library was written).